# Can someone give an example when to let switch statements use multiple case statements?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading *Javascript: the Definitive Reference*, and it says on page 93:

> On rare occasions, it is useful to write code like this that falls
>   through from one case label to the next, but 99% of the time you
>   should be very careful to end every case within a switch with a break
>   statement.

In what situation would you let a switch statement fall through to multiple case statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One useful case is when several values should have the same result:

```
switch (value) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
    action1();
    break;
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
    action2();
    break;
}
```

The empty cases will just fall though to the next. In this case there is minimal risk for confusion.

The case that the book author is worried about is when you combine actions, for example where the value `2` should have both `action2` and `action3`:

```
switch (value) {
  case 1:
    action1();
    break;
  case 2:
    action2();
    // continue with action3
  case 3:
    action3();
    break;
}
```

Forgetting a `break` is such a common mistake, that you should add a comment like above to make it clear that it was intentionally left out.

For comparison; in C# you are not allowed to just omit a `break` in a `switch`, there you have to use a `goto` instead to specify the case where the exection should continue.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've ever done that is when user input is preferred in uppercase, but acceptable in lower case:

```
switch(input){
    case 'a':
        print "Please use uppercase next time";
    case 'A':
        //do stuff here
        break;
}
```

Comment: True, though JavaScript's `print` method is for printing the page, not outputting a string.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly acceptable when you have multiple cases that should all get the same code:

```
switch(val) {
    case "aa":
    case "bb":
        // do you thing here
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the book should have stick to the facts instead of issuing this kind of recommendation. Just keep in mind that the next `case` block will be execute if the previous one does not have a `break` statement. That's useful, but can be confusing too (i.e. missing `break` statements will lead to bugs). *When* to use it is subjective, but basically you can use it when your condition is like an `or` expression:

```
if(myvar == x || myvar == y) {
    // do A
} else if (myvar == w || myvar == z) {
    // do B
} else {
    // do C
}
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
switch(myvar) {
    case x:
    case y:
        // do A
        break;
    case w:
    case z:
        // do B
        break;
    default:
        // do C
        break;
}
```

}